# Lightning script error in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, salesforce

I'm so used to having things work in Chrome and Firefox and then having to be fixed in IE that this has me well and truly stumped.

I'm trying to get DataTables to work within a Lightning component and keep getting this error: **Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Option': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.** As you can see here:

[image: Chrome error - Sorry to interrupt]

A mate at work suggested I try it in IE and it all works fine:

[image: IE Success]

So I guess my question has multiple parts, not only do I need to understand why it fails in Chrome (and Firefox, because it errors there as well) and how I might correct it, but I'd also really like to understand what's going on within Lightning for this to happen as it seems as though the culprit is aura_prod.js but I've checked the script in both environments and it's the same in each...

Any help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Quite rightly it has been pointed out that I haven't included any code, I guess the reason I didn't is because it's trivial:

```
$("#example").DataTable();
```

which is called after the table has been generated as a static table.

Comment: After 5 years in stackoverflow and almost 2k reputation - do you really think that it's possible to help without **any** line of code?

Comment: You're quite correct, bear with ;-)

Comment: Provide a working example (not only 1 line). A real-complete-live working example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You see @Dekel, I think that's the issue TBH - it seems to be less about the code and more about the way it is served via Salesforce within a Lightning component. I did ponder it being something to do with the Lightning LockerService and I really can't think of anything else excepting that it works fine in IE. The code, in this instance, isn't the thing at fault - rather it seems to be something to do with the browser and its interaction with Lightning - if you see what I mean? The line of code I provided is all that there is because, without it, a valid table is generated by the controller.

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Not a single one! Odd isn't it? The error comes from the Lightning component and is not under my control. Neither is there any error in the console in IE... the error ("Sorry to interrupt" modal) in Firefox is slightly different: TypeError: Constructor Option requires 'new' throws at https://<domain>/auraFW/javascript/-Nl7t7IjS5oiqOIuVwZRSw/aura_prod.js:548:381

Comment: Is that some code you wrote or internal of salesforce?

Comment: Internal to Salesforce.

Comment: So I guess they have a shitty code that uses some component/feature that only IE have, and there is probably nothing you could do about it... The reason that you don't see any errors is that they `try {..} catch {..}` them (and provide you with the error in the modal in your screenshot).

Comment: Sort of what I thought, but wondered if anyone else had overcome the issue. This seems to have the same issue: https://github.com/RatanPaul/Salesforce-Lightning-Dynamic-Datatable

Comment: Well... salesforce is payed solution. You should ask them, I guess :)

Comment: Might be helpful: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146370/cannot-use-select2-jquery-library-in-lightning-components-with-lorckerservice-ac

Comment: AFAIK, They override every single window, document and other global properties, so any plugin that relies on standard interfacec could fail unexpectedly. It's still new tech, though.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey I guess I need to write my own implementation of DataTables for Lightning... or wait until it becomes supported again ;-). I've had some success getting jQuery to work within a component, but it's a wee struggle at times - vanilla JS it is then, with a smattering of Aura I guess.